# How to efficiently perform this column operation on a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
+---+---+---+
| F1| F2| F3|
+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  1|
|  x|  z|  2|
|  x|  a|  4|
|  x|  a|  4|
|  x|  y|  1|
|  t| y2|  6|
|  t| y3|  4|
|  t| y4|  5|
+---+---+---+
```

I want to add another column with value as (`number of unique rows of "F1" and "F2" for each unique "F3" / total number of unique rows of "F1" and "F2"`).

For example, for the above table, below is the desired new dataframe:

```
+---+---+---+----+
| F1| F2| F3|  F4|
+---+---+---+----+
|  t| y4|  5| 1/6|
|  x|  y|  1| 1/6|
|  x|  y|  1| 1/6|
|  x|  z|  2| 1/6|
|  t| y2|  6| 1/6|
|  t| y3|  4| 2/6|
|  x|  a|  4| 2/6|
|  x|  a|  4| 2/6|
+---+---+---+----+
```

Note: in case of `F3 = 4`, there are only `2` unique `F1` and `F2` = `{(t, y3), (x, a)}`. Therefore, for all occurrences of `F3 = 4`, `F4` will be `2/(total number of unique ordered pairs of F1 and F2. Here there are 6 such pairs)`

How to achieve the above transformation in Spark Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just learnt trying to solve your problem, that you can't use Distinct functions while performing Window over DataFrames.

So what I did is create an temporary DataFrame and join it with the initial to obtain your desired results :

```
case class Dog(F1:String, F2: String, F3: Int)
val df = Seq(Dog("x", "y", 1), Dog("x", "z", 2), Dog("x", "a", 4), Dog("x", "a", 4), Dog("x", "y", 1), Dog("t", "y2", 6), Dog("t", "y3", 4), Dog("t", "y4", 5)).toDF
val unique_F1_F2 = df.select("F1", "F2").distinct.count
val dd = df.withColumn("X1", concat(col("F1"), col("F2")))
           .groupBy("F3")
           .agg(countDistinct(col("X1")).as("distinct_count"))
val final_df = dd.join(df, "F3")
                 .withColumn("F4", col("distinct_count")/unique_F1_F2)
                 .drop("distinct_count")
final_df.show
+---+---+---+-------------------+
| F3| F1| F2|                 F4|
+---+---+---+-------------------+
|  1|  x|  y|0.16666666666666666|
|  1|  x|  y|0.16666666666666666|
|  6|  t| y2|0.16666666666666666|
|  5|  t| y4|0.16666666666666666|
|  4|  t| y3| 0.3333333333333333|
|  4|  x|  a| 0.3333333333333333|
|  4|  x|  a| 0.3333333333333333|
|  2|  x|  z|0.16666666666666666|
+---+---+---+-------------------+
```

I hope this is what you expected !

EDIT : I changed df.count to unique_F1_F2

Comment: how about max(rank()) and orderBy($"F1", $"F2" desc) ?

Comment: which one will be more efficient in terms of time and space complexity?

Comment: Also, why is f4 = 0.25 when F3 =4. As mentioned in the problem description, it should have been F4 = 2/6 = 0.33333333, for all F3 = 4 as 4 occurs in 2 unique pairs of (F1, F2) i.e., {(x, a), (t, y3)}, out of the all 6 unique ordered pairs of (F1, F2) = {(x, y), (t, y2), (t, y4), (t, y3), (x, a), (x, z)}.

Comment: And for all F3 = 1, f4 should have been 1/6 = 0.16666666, as F3 = 1 occured for only 1 "unique" ordered pair of F1 and F2 out of 6 unique (F1, F2) pairs

Comment: My mistake I didn't you wanted the count of unique F1 / F2, I will change the last line with df.count

Comment: I am sorry, if I am making myself very confusing. To summarize, F4 should be = (number of unique ordered pairs of (F1, F2) having F3) / (total number of unique ordered pairs of (F1, F2))

Comment: Is it better now ?